# How to make a Wordpress post only visible for the author and through a direct link?

Tags: wordpress, posts, author

I want to make a Wordpress site where users can register them self. They only need the ability to update there profile and write a post. This post should be only visible to the author or through a direct link.

Does anybody know how I can make the post of the author invisible on the website but when the author logs in the post is visible and when someone uses the direct link to the post it's also visible. Is there some kind of plugin what can do this or some kind of code which I can edit so this will work.

Also there are multiple authors with each there own posts.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to your posts
2. Open the desired one.
3. Set post visibility to **Private**

Also you can vizit this page:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/let-author-only-see-their-posts